# download url for nuget packages on JFrog with C#

Tags: c#, nuget, jfrog-container-registry

I'm writing a custom NuGet package comparer, for that I need to download the packages locally and unpack them.
For the Microsoft NuGet repository it is very easy, [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/package-base-address-resource#download-package-content-nupkg) describes the url format for downloading any package. It is like this:

```
https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/{packageId}/{version}/{packageId}.{version}.nupkg
```

Now I need to use JFrog and I can not figure out how I would download the NuGet packages. I am coding this project in C#.

**How can I download nuget packages from JFrog, using C#?**